# How to decorate my React component correctly when exporting the module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-dnd

I am trying to add the @DragDropContext decorator on my class but I am getting an error when I load it in my browser.

My component looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd';
import { HTML5Backend } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

@DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)

class UserShowView extends React.Component {

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserShowView);
```

This is what the error looks like in chrome console:

> bundle.js:977 Uncaught Error: Expected the backend to be a function or
>   an ES6 module exporting a default function. Read more:
>   http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drag-drop-context.html

My babelrc file:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"],
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["react-hmre"]
    }
  }
}
```

packages.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node tools/srcServer.js",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest",
    "lint": "eslint --max-warnings=0 src test",
    "test:watch": "NODE_ENV=test jest --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-display-name": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "colors": "^1.1.2",
    "compression": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "eslint-watch": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "jest": "^22.0.6",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^2.0.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.10.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dnd": "^2.5.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },

}
```

What am I doing wrong or am I missing a babel preset?

**Is my "transform-decorators-legacy" even working?**

Comment: This might be something completely wrong, but isn't what you're doing the ES7 way of going with it? (On the docs the es7 way uses `@DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)` where as the ES6 way (going by the error that it expects ES6) is `export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(YourApp);` according to the docs

Comment: @Simplicity that's true, but either way how would I do it the ES6 way when I have this: ```export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserShowView);```

Comment: _I think_ you can use the `compose` export from the `redux` library to export the component with both the HOC like so: `export default 
compose(connect(mapStateToProps), DragDropContext(HTML5Backend))(UserShowView)`

Comment: @Simplicity I have the transform-decorators-legacy in my babelrc so that should make it work.

Comment: Reading the documentation could it be that you need to import the module without the brackets? `import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';`

Comment: @ieldanr do you want to give a formal answer, that seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error messages shows, `@DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)` is expecting a module or function.

From the [documentation](http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-html5-backend.html) you should be importing the `HTML5Backend` module with:

`import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';`

Since you are using

`import { HTML5Backend } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';`

You are trying to import a specific export that doesn't exist thus `DragDropContext` showing the error.

Importing with curly brackets is for specific exports vs without curly brackets which is for default exports.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
for more information on different ways of importing modules and functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the curly braces around HTML5Backend

`import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';`

http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drag-drop-context.html#usage